# Jquery Autocomplete demo not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Hi everyone and thank you for the time dedicated for reading this post.
First, please note i am new to this so please don't kill me if i ask stupid questions or if i missed something really obvious.

I would like to note that I have searched the forums and read several items here in regards to my issue without any success.

My problem: I am trying to implement the most basic of the jquery autocomplete (http://www.jqueryautocomplete.com/jquery-autocomplete-json-example.html)

My code:

```
<head>

<script src="js/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery/jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery/jquery.ui.widget.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery/jquery.ui.position.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery/jquery.ui.autocomplete.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css"/>

</head>

<body>

<input type="text" id="search" />

</body>

<script>
var data = [
    {"label" : "Aragorn"},
    {"label" : "Arwen"},
    {"label" : "Bilbo Baggins"},
    {"label" : "Boromir"},
    {"label" : "Frodo Baggins"},
    {"label" : "Gandalf"},
    {"label" : "Gimli"},
    {"label" : "Gollum"},
    {"label" : "Legolas"},
    {"label" : "Meriadoc Merry Brandybuck"},
    {"label" : "Peregrin Pippin Took"},
    {"label" : "Samwise Gamgee"}
    ];
$(function() {
$( "#search" ).autocomplete(
{
     source:data
})
});
</script>
```

I have tried adding the $(document).ready(function() without any success. am i missing something really really stupid ?

Thanks in advance for your help !!! much appreciated.

Comment: see the console , what error you are getting, have you linked the jquery files properly or simply copied the code from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Download** these files first

```
<script src="js/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery/jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery/jquery.ui.widget.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery/jquery.ui.position.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery/jquery.ui.autocomplete.min.js"></script>
```

then add it in `js` folder in your project,it will work

Answer (score 0):

Please check the consoles for any error.I believe that you have not added all the js file in the project directory. Everything seems to work perfectly in Fiddle.Please ensure you add all the js with correct script src for them

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EBduF/576/)**

```
$(function() {
 $( "#search" ).autocomplete(
 {
 source:data
 })
});
```